# React router - Update URL hash without re-rendering page

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Using [react-router](https://github.com/rackt/react-router) I'm looking for a way to update the page URL / hash, without the router re-rendering the whole page.

I am developing a full page carousel, and would like each slide to have it's own URL (allowing the user to refresh the page and return to the correct slide). The carousel will later have swipe similar to [this demo](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/), which means the *next* slide is pre-rendered.

A stripped down version of my carousel is available [here](http://jsfiddle.net/CptLemming/d6oysfbh/1/).

The current slide change looks like this:

```
onClickLeft: function() {
  this.setState({
    selected: this.state.selected - 1
  });
}
```

This works fine, with no URL updates. What I really want is:

```
mixin: [Navigation],
onClickLeft: function() {
  this.transitionTo('carousel-slide', {num: this.state.selected + 1});
}
```

This would set the prop of the current slide, allowing the carousel to animate. However using this method now causes the page to re-render and no animation is displayed.

I have seen the `ReactCSSTransitionGroup` used for route transitions, however this seems geared toward rendering a new page and transitioning out the old one.

If there's already a way to achieve what I'm looking for, and I've missed it, could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Try changing `this.props.activeRouteHandler()` to `this.props.activeRouteHandler({key: "test"})` in your handler.  Does this help?

Comment: Though I have no idea why, this worked! I had to combine this with `componentWillReceiveProps` to catch the updated props and call `setState`, but still, fantastic! Fancy adding this as an answer so I can accept?

Comment: It was just a hunch, and I didn't have the time to test it.  Answer below :-)

Comment: Check out my answer at the bottom for `react router v4`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### 1.0

react-router no longer sets a key on your routes. If you do need to set a key from a route handler, put it on a surrounding element.

```
return (
  <div key={this.props.params.bookId}>
    {this.props.children}
  </div>
);
```

### 0.13

It's now `<ReactRouter.RouteHandler key="anything" />`, but this is also no longer really needed due to changes in react-router.  See the changelog for more details.

## 0.12

Currently, react-router sets a key on your handler based on the current route.  When react does its diff, and notices a different key, it throws out the entire subtree both in virtual and real dom, and rerenders.

To prevent this, you can override react-router's key when using activeRouteHandler()

```
this.props.activeRouteHandler({key: "anything"})
```

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand It's unclear, from the changelog, what to do now to accomplish this in React Router vs 1.0.0 with the new history module. Any chance you could update this or point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 11):

It is a pain to work with react-router because it involves breaking changes in every major and minor release

**React Router v2.0 rc5**

```
import { hashHistory } from 'react-router'
this.props.location.query.t = key;
hashHistory.replace(this.props.location);
```

Comment: @Kousha, `hashHistory` is for paths set on the URL _after_ the `#`.  `browserHistory` is used for non-hashed URL like your starting example.

Comment: IS there any way for v 4.0? or higher

Comment: Check my answer for v4

Answer (score 6):

For **React router v4** you need to use `history` and pass it as prop to the `Router`. `Router` will then pass `history` object to your component as a prop and you can use it like so:

```
// In your component

this.props.history.push("#testing")
```

History file

```
// history.js 
import createHistory from "history/createBrowserHistory";

export default createHistory();
```

Then, wherever you are declaring your router, pass the history prop

```
import history from "./history";
import { Router } from "react-router-dom";

    <Router history={history}>
      // ... Your component
    </Router>
```

Comment: Do you know how make this work in v5? I get this in the console: “Warning: Please use `require("history").createBrowserHistory` instead of `require("history/createBrowserHistory")`. Support for the latter will be removed in the next major release.” I tried the suggestion, but it broke the site.

Comment: In v5 modifying the history will also rerender the page.

Answer (score 3):

**React Router v6**

**JavaScript**

If you really want to do this with React Router, you can look at some workarounds in [this issue](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/7634) or look at the HTML solution below. However, I would just recommend doing it using the window object.

If you want it plain and simple, set the hash like this:
`window.location.hash = '#newHash'`.

If you don't want to push something to the history stack, use `window.location.replace`, like in the following example:
`window.location.replace('#newHash')`.

**HTML *(`<Link>`)***

Use an anchor tag, if you only want to link to a hash, and you don't need any React Router features.

If you just want to create a `<Link to="">` element, you can set `reloadDocument` to true, like in the following example:
`<Link reloadDocument to="#test"></Link>`. This skips client side routing and lets the browser handle the transition normally as it were an anchor tag. Read more about it [here](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#link). Make sure React Router renders the `to="[this link]"` link correctly! If you want, like me, that the hash will not get pushed to the user's history, you also need to set the `replace` attribute on the link element to true. However, this solution does not work, if you have search parameters.

Comment: "If you want it plain and simple, set the hash like this" yes, plain and simple but the entire page rerenders after that.