# How can I follow a react-router Link without it being pushed to history, but keep URL change?

Tags: url, history, react-router

I want to change URL when clicking on component Links, same way they currently change by default, but without them being pushed to browser history.
I've found the following working for someone [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26239154/react-router-update-url-hash-without-re-rendering-page):

`this.props.activeRouteHandler({key: "anystring"})`

but I don't know where should I place it and if it even works anymore. Can someone give me an example?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For version `^0.13.3` I had to create custom MyLink component same as Link but with replaced `this.transitionTo` to `this.replaceWith`.

For version `^1.0.x` API changed:

`var { History } = require('react-router')
...
mixins: [ History ]
...
this.history.pushState(null, '/newPathName')`

Answer (score 3):

Use the `replace` property of `Link` and set it to `true`.

Here is a link to the documentation: https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Link

ex.

```
<Link to=[your_url] replace={true}>
  ...
</Link>
```

Answer (score 0):

In case someone wants to use `useNavigate` add an object as a second argument with `{replace: true}`, for example:

```
const navigation = useNavigate();
navigation(
    "toYour/newPath/", 
    {
        replace: true,
    });
```