# Changing the URL Without Triggering a Rerender

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to figure out how to do this. I've got a parameters object that looks like this:

```
{
  param1: value,
  param2: value2,
  filers:[
    filter1, 
    filter2
  ]
}
```

here is my example code, that is called within the `getInitialState` method.

```
var parameters = {PARAMETERS_OBJECT}
this.transitionTo(route, null, parameters);
```

What this is doing is rerendering the page 3 times, and it's completely screwing up the URL as well as making extra API calls.

Is there any way I could initialize the URL that would not result in a rerender or a redirect?

EDIT: I'm using `react-router`

Basically, here is the use case here.

The page is loaded: `/url`
Upon loading the page, I want to append `?queryString=this&that=this` to the end of the base url without triggering a redirect or a rerender.

Comment: I assume you are using react-router?  May want to add this info to your question, as well as provide a more complete description of the behavior you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Will do, sorry about that.

Comment: Why do you do transitionTo inside getInitialState? It doesn't make sense.

Comment: @MikhailChibel I'm using the URL as the point of truth for this particular component, rather than the state. I need to update the URL on the initial render for state purposes. Or at least, that's the theory. I'm by no means a pro at React haha. The reason is, I'd like to use `this.props.query` to update my component (aka, the URL)

Comment: That's fine, but the transitionTo method is actually triggering the transition.  Also, what versions of react and react-router are you using? In the latest version of react-router you should use push method

Comment: @MikhailChibel Its version 0.13.0.

Comment: @Kris have you checked  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26239154/react-router-update-url-hash-without-re-rendering-page

Comment: You should be using the componentWillReceiveProps to determine if it should call the api or not. if you are in a situation where you dont want to update then dont call it.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use transitionTo inside `getInitialState` method. For React-router v2+ don't use `transitionTo` but rather `push` method on the history.

**EDIT**

The issue discussed [here](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/issues/2335)

Comment: Where should either one of these be called in order to prime the initial state?

Comment: You don't want to open different page when initializing the component, do you? You want to have url in the state, this is ok but why do you need to navigate? Or you trying to build Url from parameters? Please put more code to the question so it will be clear what are you trying to do.

Comment: I've updated my question. I appreciate all of the help!