# React-router working with list

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a list of users and a sidebar
after clicking on a list item, i get a full information about user in a sidebar, but i don't know how to change "url" when a user is being clicked.

I don,t need to render another page, i just need to change window "href" after clicking on a user, this link should be reusable, i mean i can send it to someone and he will see the clicked before user.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[react-router-redux](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux) package give you a reducer, actions to do what you want.

Comment: can you write some example?

Comment: Sorry guy, do you redux in you application ?

Comment: Ok so react-router have a object hashHistory and a method 'replace', check this post for more informations http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26239154/react-router-update-url-hash-without-re-rendering-page#answer-34914840

Comment: thank you, I tried it and it work, the url was chaged but I cant use this link, I cant send it to someone so he can see exact action i am interested in